# Clearing EEPROM

Tags: c++, eeprom

I'm trying to clear my EEPROM and am using this code:

```
#include <EEPROM.h>
void setup()
{
// write a 0 to all 4096 bytes of the EEPROM
for (int i = 0; i < 4096; i++)
EEPROM.write(i, 0);

delay(9999999);
}

void loop()
{
}
```

I don't see a problem with it but it is ineffective.  Am I missing something?

Comment: from memory, you need `EEPROM.commit();` or maybe `EEPROM.end();` after writing

Comment: Aaaaaah! Of course! Thank you.  Stupid stuff like this drives me crazy.

Comment: Although, that MAY just be on the ESP8266 judging from the sample sketches

Comment: What do you mean "ineffective"? The EEPROM is not cleared? Or only some is? If so, how do you know? Which Arduino do you have?

Comment: Ineffective in thwt the eeprom was not erased.  Nothing changed after I ran this sketch.  I saved "TEST01" to eeprom and it was still there after I tried to erase it.

Comment: Note that empty EEPROM is all 1s, not all 0s. Write `-1` instead.

Comment: I am nitpicking but... when you `EEPROM.write()`, you are actually erasing an EEPROM cell, **then** writing a new value into it. This takes 3.4 ms, irrespective of the value written. You could do an erase-only operation, which takes only 1.8 ms. It looks, though, like this cannot be done with the Arduino EEPROM library, and not even with <avr/eeprom.h> from avr-libc. You would have to access the EEPROM address and control registers directly, as documented in the datasheet of the MCU.

Comment: Thankyou for this sketch , It works perfectly for me. I added a two lines to turn on LED after the sketch completed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorial [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/EEPROMClear) is very clear about how to clear the contents of the Atmel's EEPROM.  I only see 2 major difference.  The tutorial finds the size of the EEPROM through a function call.  Probably much safer.  And there is no call to a delay() function.

The tutorial does include lighting up an LED when finished.  And @Edgar Bonet is correct that erasing an EEPROM (altering each [floating gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-gate_MOSFET) with in the chip) does take time.  And you have no way to known when the EEPROM clearing is finished in your code.

It is possible you are forcing your code to stop before it is finished.  In which case it would appear the EEPROM is not completely cleared.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for helping me out.  This is what I ended up using (ESP8266 1.0 12E with Arduino IDE):

```
#include <EEPROM.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  EEPROM.begin(512);
  delay(5000);
  Serial.println("clearing EEPROM...");
  // write a 0 to first 1000 bytes of the EEPROM
  for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
    EEPROM.write(i, -1);
 }
  EEPROM.commit();
  delay(5000);
  Serial.println("Reading EEPROM ssid");
  String esid;
  for (int i = 0; i < 64; ++i)
  {
    esid += char(EEPROM.read(i));
  }
  Serial.print("SSID: ");
  Serial.println(esid);
  Serial.println("Reading EEPROM pass");
  String epass = "";
  for (int i = 64; i < 128; ++i)
  {
    epass += char(EEPROM.read(i));
  }
  Serial.print("PASS: ");
  Serial.println(epass);
}

void loop()
{
}
```

It's probably longer than it has to be but I pulled stuff from other sketches I've worked on and prioritize function over form.  This writes a "-1" to the first 1000 bytes and then prints the first 128 bytes.  Since I am only concerned about the first 50 bytes or so this was sufficient for my needs.